# How to open info bubble on hover

Tags: javascript, here-api

I have trouble coming with a solution to the stated problem.
It seems that there is some other way of adding an event listener to the marker than this proposed in official example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/0apmc5un/).

The troublesome piece of code in question:

```
    group.addEventListener('mouseover', function (evt) {
    // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
    // for all objects that it contains
    console.log(`Is it working yet?`)
    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
      // read custom data
      content: evt.target.getData()
    });
    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
  }, false);
```

Comment: I cannot understand why reactjs tag is attached to this question. It would be great if instead of linking to an external source, you cut the extra parts and reproduce a somewhat workable example here so we can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there. The event that you want to listen to is called *pointermove*:

```
group.addEventListener('pointermove', function (evt) {
    // event target is the marker itself, group is a parent event target
    // for all objects that it contains
    console.log(`Is it working yet?`)
    var bubble =  new H.ui.InfoBubble(evt.target.getPosition(), {
      // read custom data
      content: evt.target.getData()
    });
    // show info bubble
    ui.addBubble(bubble);
}, false);
```

See the **[map events guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/topics/events.html)**

Comment: What about removing Bubble on mouse leave?
I have difficulty with
a). finding event to remove bubble on,
b). finding method with which I could remove/destroy bubble.
`const marker = new window.H.map.Marker({ lat, lng }, { icon });
marker.addEventListener(
   'pointermove',
   (evt) => {
    this.createInfoBubble();
    ui.addBubble(this.bubble);
   },
   false
  );
marker.addEventListener(
   'pointerleave',
   (evt) => {
    console.log('Pointer leave')
    ui.removeBubble(this.bubble);
    ui.dispose(this.bubble);
    this.bubble = null;
   },
   false
  );`

Answer (score 1):

there are two on event functions you can use. 'mouseover' and 'mouseleave'. mouseover activates when your mouse enters the area of the element and mouseleave activates when your mouse leave de area.

```
element.addEventListener('mouseover', function(evt) {
   /// make bubble appear
});

element.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(evt) {
   /// make bubble disappear
});
```